# Is it possible to each php in like css code?

Tags: php, css

I want to include a php script in a css file:

```
<?php
$str = "5px";
echo $str;
?>
```

and then

```
.header {
font-size: $str;
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: if you have php inside  you must call filename.php  and not filename.css .. filename.css don't invoce the php interpreter

Comment: Look up LESS, that will let you do things like that http://lesscss.org/

Comment: Sounds like this may be an XY problem. It will probably be better to keep a static CSS file and dynamically add or change classes on HTML elements in your PHP script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not like that. CSS isn't a programming language, and has NOTHING to do with PHP.

You can, however, have PHP generate the CSS:

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.php" ... />
```

foo.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
$str = '5px';
?>

.header {
    font-size: '<?php echo $str; ?>';
}
```

Note that since you'r GENERATING css, you have to make absolutely SURE that whatever PHP outputs will be valid for the context the output is going into. It is very easy to output something that'll be a CSS syntax error and kill the rest of the CSS file.